# Constructing equivalent (to a polynomial-time degree) decision problems from function problems

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, decision-problem

Let's say we're some function problem, $R \subseteq \Sigma^* \times \Sigma^*$, where $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$ and some oracle $O_R$ that solves $R$.

Now, we're given some language, $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ and an associated oracle $O_L$ that solves $L$.

We say $R =_{poly} L$ if a machine equipped with $O_L$ can solve $R$ AND a machine equipped with $O_R$ can solve $L$.

Is there some function that maps $f \colon \mathcal{P}(\Sigma^* \times \Sigma^*) \mapsto \mathcal{P}(\Sigma^*)$ such that $R =_{poly} f(R) \: \forall R$?

My requirement for $f$ is that it must computable. As a bonus, and this isn't really quantifiable, but I would like for it to be "neat;" i.e. it should be able to be written as a "short" human-readable algorithm in the English language.

My question basically boils down to converting function problems to decision problems, such that they are polynomial-time equivalent problems.

Comment: The line "Is there some function" is confusing to me. Above you defined $=_{poly}$ as a relation between relations (function problems) and languages. Instead, in this line $\omega =_{poly} f(\omega)$ uses it between a pair of words and a word, which makes no sense. I believe you want something like $R =_{poly} f(R)$ and $f : \mathcal{P}(\Sigma^*\times\Sigma^*) \to \mathcal{P}(\Sigma^*)$.

Comment: @chi Yes, that is correct. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Special case: computing a (single-valued) function

In the special case where the relation $R$ corresponds to a (single-valued) function, call it $g$, then yes, there is an equivalence.  Suppose the function problem is to compute the function $g$.  Define the language $L$ by

$$L=\{\langle x,i,b \rangle \mid x \in \{0,1\}^*, g(x)_i=b\},$$

i.e., $L$ consists of all triples $\langle x,i,b \rangle$ such that the $i$th bit of the output is $b$ when the input is $x$.  Assume that we consider $g(x)_i$ to be $\bot$ if $i$ is past the end of $g(x)$.

Then given an algorithm or oracle to decide $L$, you can immediately compute $g$ (by computing it a bit at a time, trying all three possibilities for $b$ for each $i$), and given an algorithm or oracle to compute $g$, you can immediately decide $L$.  Moreover this a polynomial-time reduction in both directions, assuming the length of $g(x)$ is polynomial in the length of $x$.

## General case

I don't know.  I am not aware of any way to define such an equivalence, for a general relation $R$ (which might be "multi-valued").

Comment: Can this be extended to arbitrary binary relations (as function problems are)? Right now, this only works for functions ($g$ is a function).

Comment: Your construction for the multivalued case doesn't work. While $R$ is going to be polytime reducible to $L$, there is no reason why $L$ would be polytime reducible to $R$. If we just get some output from $R$, we don't know whether there is a different output that would indeed extend $s$ or not.

Comment: @Arno, oops, thank you for correcting my erroneous answer.